# Show empty list items with loading animation until the whole list is loaded in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation

[image]

I want to achieve something like this

[image]
 And this

How can I show this kind of empty empty list as in udemy combined with some animation like in snapchat until whole list is loaded

Comment: Just add a view with the design you want and hide the listview, when the loading is done hide the placeholder view and make the ListView visible

Comment: https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you explained a bit better I'm editing this answer.

In order to do something similar to SkyScanner, display fake placeholders because you can't retrieve any previous information about the data you must follow these steps:

[image: SkyScanner fake placeholders]

- For the animation have a look on Lottie library you can do a really nice animation, and make this animation run in loop until you have your call response, check the library here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android
  Lottie is a nice way to do vectors animation and it uses json file so it's really light, but you can also do the animations on the old style of course.
- For the placeholder the logic is this: You are going to switch the content of your data set, the adapter is going to check, if the content inside the data set is the kind of real data you want to display it is going to fill with the real xml and use the real recyclerview holder, if the kind of that is not the real data you are going to inflate the row with the placeholder xml (the same size and disposition to achieve the result you are looking for) and a new recyclerview holder for placeholder so you can control the row behaviour, for example control your animation or intercale object behaviour based on position.

Consider an object YourCustomObject as the holder of your real data, but can be any kind as long you do a different kind of data for your fake placeholder, the logic inside the adapter is this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mDataSet.get(position) instanceof YourCustomObject ? VIEW_TYPE_DATA : VIEW_TYPE_PLACEHOLDER;
}
```

Then

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DATA) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_real_data, parent, false);
        holder = new RealDataHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_placeholder, parent, false);
        holder = new PlaceholderHolder(v);
    }
    return holder;
}
```

Don't forget to check the type of the Holder on onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof RealDataHolder) {
YourCustomObject data = (YourCustomObject) dataSet.get(position);
(...)
```

Don't forget that inside the adapter your dataSet is a list of Object (java class)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like you didn't get what I want, I mean empty placeholder should be there before getting the exact number of list items doesn't matter weather you have 1 or 50 it should display let's say 10 empty placeholders and then the full list appears

Comment: Hmmmm, I thought about you when I was using SkyScanner's app, they do like this, a fake placeholder, use the same code I provided and replace your dataSet for a different kind of your object. The code above is to check the kind of data into your data set and display a placeholder into it, so what is missing is just switch the data content of your source for 10 (n) different objects every time you trigger a new call to fetch info. Plus, if you want  a nice placeholder I keep my suggestion to use Lottie, is a fantastic and light library to achieve nice animations.